# Get the type of array element in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, integer

I have the following method:

```
public static int arraySum(Object obj) {
}
```

The method should return the sum of all elements in obj; a precondition for this method is that `obj` be an Integer array of any dimension, i.e. `Integer`, `Integer[]`, `Integer[][]`, so on.

In order to write the body of the method `arraySum()`, I'm using a foreach loop and recursion; however, for the foreach loop I need to know which type the elements of obj are. Is there a way to find out the type (i.e. `Integer`, `Integer[]`, etc.) of `obj`?

EDIT: This is for an assignment for my CS course. I don't want to simply ask how to write the method, that's why I'm asking such a specific question.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're not just using 2 overloads?

Comment: if(myarray[I] instanceof type) ....; think this is what you want?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Not sure what an overload is :P

Comment: @pedromss `obj` could have any number of dimensions, meaning lots and lots of if statements

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670972/variable-dimensioned-array-in-java. You should have a good reason of wanting to do this. It sounds like a XY problem to me. Maybe you should give us more context on why you want to do this.

Comment: Choose the number of brackets at the start of `obj.getClass().getName()` (e.g. `[[Ljava.lang.Integer`) as the recursion depth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's simpler than you think:

```
public static int arraySum(Object obj) {
    if (obj.getClass() == Integer.class)
        return ((Integer) obj).intValue();

    int sum = 0;
    for (Object o : (Object[]) obj)
        sum += arraySum(o);

    return sum;
}
```

Basically we exploit the fact that an `Integer` array of any dimension is still an `Object[]`.

---

```
Object obj = new Integer[][][]{{{1,2,3}},{{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},{{10}}};

System.out.println(arraySum(obj));
```

```
55
```

Comment: This will cause a `ClassCastException` if you call it like this `arraySum(new Object())`. There should be an additional check for an array type `obj.getClass().isArray()` before the cast in the for loop and of course a null check.

Comment: @A4L *"a precondition for this method is that `obj` be an Integer array of any dimension"* Although the OP can add those checks if he really needs them. It's a trivial addition, and the core of the method will remain the same.

Comment: OP must then make sure to pass only arrays to it. +1 still an elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple `instanceof`, for example:

```
if (obj instanceof Integer[][]) 
    System.out.println("2d");
if (obj instanceof Integer[]) 
    System.out.println("1d");
if (obj instanceof Integer) 
    System.out.println("0d");
```